# How to find the curve of the intersection between the cylinder $z=x^3$ and the equation of the plane $12x+z-32=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I’m not sure how to go about this since it’s unlike the examples I’ve seen before, using $x^2$ and $y^2$ only.

Comment: Have you tried solving the system of two equations for $\,x,z\,$?

Answer (score 1):

The real solution to $x^3+12x-32=0$ is $x=2$, we subtitute in $12x+z=32$ then $z=8$.

The intersection is the line $(2, t, 8)$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$